# How to process a html selectbox through PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm running into some trouble with a script I've made.
I've created a form, and everything of this form is getting submitted, however... I'm getting an error on the gender selection part.

Now this is how my selectbox looks like:

```
<select dir="rtl" name="GENDER">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

When I process the form, this is the error I am getting:
`Notice: Undefined index: GENDER in ***\www\ucp\usercharacters.php on line 250`

This is line 250-252:

```
$gender = $db->escapeString($_POST["GENDER"]);
$birthdate = $db->escapeString($_POST["BD"]);
$firstname = $db->escapeString($_POST["FN"]);
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Additionally, does that build some SQL query? Then please use prepared statements instead of escaping single strings

Comment: There is nothing to debug, the only value not getting passed here is GENDER. There is no sql query that follows the succes of the form. I didn't write this yet. I always make the form, test it. Make the processing part, test it. And then I'll add the query. I haven't reached that part yet. It does by the way, show every statement correctly. It just doesn't pass the GENDER value along. I have tried echoing both $gender and $_POST["GENDER"] resulting in the same undefined index error.

Comment: Nothing to debug, but an error happens? Strange combination. Is that form even sent using POST? Have you checked whether the form was sent before you try to access `$_POST`?

Comment: I have, how can the rest of the form be correct if I didn't use POST or if it wasn't being sent? I have this if statement and it works: if(isset($_POST["FN"]))

Comment: I have solved it. <option value="">Select</option> When there was no option selected there was no value set.